# LilyPond: rests making an empty whole measure

Tags: lilypond, rests

I am writing (in LilyPond) the beautiful lyrical waltz of Shostakovich, and I am getting a whole measure empty. What I want to achieve is the following:
[image: Four measures of a piano score, with three whole measure rests in the right hand]

But I am getting this:
[image: Four measures of a piano score, with three misaligned whole measure rests and blank measure in the right hand]

I'd tried several combinations of rest but none are working, the best I can get is what I've show here.

My current code looks like this:
(I use Italian language, but certainly you will see the point)

```
\language "italiano"
upper = \relative do' {
\clef treble
\key fa \major
\time 3/4
    r1
    r1
    r1
    r8 do8 re mi fa sol
}

lower = \relative do {
\clef bass
\key fa \major
\time 3/4
    fa,4 <do' fa la>4 <do fa la>^.
    do, <do' fa la> <do fa la>^.
    fa, <do' fa la> <do fa la>^.
    do , <do' fa la> <do fa la>^.
}

\score {
\new PianoStaff <<
\new Staff = "upper" \upper
\new Staff = "lower" \lower
>>
\layout { }
\midi { }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work properly?

Comment: Including bar checks would've generated some warning messages that might've helped you track this down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simple as:

`R1 * 3/4`

Read a whole-bar rest. Which is 4 quarter notes. 4 quarter notes divided by 4, times by 3 is a whole-bar rest in 3/4 time!

---

**Edit TLTR**

They are not whole-note rests, either in 3/4 or 4/4 time but whole-bar rests, to be clear. They have a default value of 4 quarters.

> **My way**
>
> > Larger than 4 quarter-notes: 5/4  is `R1 * 5/4`
> > Equal to 4 quarter-notes: 4/4 is `R1 * 1/1`, simply `R1`
> > Smaller than 4 quarter-notes: 3/4 time is `R1 * 3/4`
>
> The fraction **mirrors** the time signature.

I'm seeing it as a whole-bar is 100%, more than 4 quarters is more than 100%, less than 4 quarters is less than 100%.

While the documentation is of course correct and doesn't state the fraction way, apart from larger than 4 quarter-notes,(and @Aaron's answer should probably be the correct answer), I think there are valid reasons for using fractions:

- fraction **mirrors** the time signature
- introduces the fraction of a note concept early-on in learning lilypond, it's particularly used in:

  - tuplets e.g. `\tuplet 3/2 { c8 c c}` (but this is 3 in space of 2, not tech. a fraction)
  - placement of delayed ornaments e.g `{ c8 * 1/4 s\trill s\turn s\prall d8 }`
  - other places like spacing
- confusion: if I see `2`, I expect to see a half-note not a whole-note (half-notes have the additional pain of looking like whole-notes). With `1` I'm always seeing whole-note symbol.

Comment: Ha ha, indeed looked like a quarter rest was floating over there and the 3/4 did pretty well! You made my day Owain. Thanks

Comment: In the question I noticed that each of the rests had strange horizontal placement within its measure. With your explanation, now I see that the rests are placed over every fourth quarter note.

Comment: @shoover I tried to expand and make my answer and make it more clearer.

Comment: Small correction: the documentation does give the fraction option. It uses the example of: `\time 13/8` // 
`R1*13/8 | R1*13/8*12 |`, demonstrating a single-bar and mutli-bar rest.

Comment: Yeah, the distinction is there. Got to be careful about language single-bar and mutli-bar rest as `\override MultiMeasureRest.staff-position = 2` works on both, there's no `SingleMeasureRest`. Ha, ha can go on forever about quirks of LP, even in docs "Full measure rests" never heard the term1

Answer (score 7):

Use a capital `R2.` (including the "dot" for dotted half-note) for your rests to indicate a full-bar rest. See here: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rests#full-measure-rests

Based on the rest placement, Lilypond is interpreting your rests as lasting four beats, thus crossing the bar lines. That seems to be why the blank measure occurs: it's three of the four beats of the third rest.